# How to use a .json file generated by a discord bot as a database file for a c# program?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, discord

So I have a bot that generates this file:

```
"223800261297176576" : {
    "129592273850597376" : {
        "balance" : 750,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-08 18:00:53",
        "name" : "Nathiri"
    },
    "180444644650385409" : {
        "balance" : 950,
        "created_at" : "2016-11-01 14:55:11",
        "name" : "WAC"
    },
    "180456532083867650" : {
        "balance" : 1150,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-08 18:12:24",
        "name" : "WiNDOGE_Master"
    },
    "194634355820199936" : {
        "balance" : 0,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-16 15:07:55",
        "name" : "DogeBot"
    },
    "195889991073660929" : {
        "balance" : 750,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-24 18:47:25",
        "name" : "Mikey"
    },
    "218499966652383232" : {
        "balance" : 1250,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-02 17:29:18",
        "name" : "[CDHG]PhoenixDeFalco"
    },
    "223084038846545920" : {
        "balance" : 300,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-11 19:24:36",
        "name" : "spyty06"
    },
    "228987707571830784" : {
        "balance" : 700,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-11 16:06:13",
        "name" : "[CDHG]CarrieDeFalco"
    },
    "229026428706881537" : {
        "balance" : 500,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-02 17:40:16",
        "name" : "[CDHG] commander spyty06"
    },
    "229347464065449984" : {
        "balance" : 750,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-29 20:24:44",
        "name" : "FaZe King"
    },
    "238783223965024273" : {
        "balance" : 750,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-25 18:40:11",
        "name" : "[CDHG]JacenDeFalco"
    },
    "242017771200708609" : {
        "balance" : 1845,
        "created_at" : "2016-10-29 20:21:27",
        "name" : "StarRoseDeFalco"
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I get a C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2015 to read this file and use the information in it to alter the various fields in the form automatically? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VKe.jpg) is what the form looks like.

If anyone could help me make the program read the .json and use it as data to put into the boxes on the form, I would be very grateful...Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @itsme86 I've tried to get it to read the file by `using bank.json`, i tried `import bank.json`, and I've also tried copying the code from `bank.json` directly into the form1.cs code file...nothing has worked...I'm officially stumped.

Answer (score 1):

first convert the Json to xml

```
 XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

then use XmlElement, to start working with the data itself.

Comment: where do i put `XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);`? Does that go in `bank.json`, or in the cs file for my forms app?

Comment: its in the .cs file, create a Method that converts your json data to xml.

Comment: from there, the data would look something like this
<root>
     <field1>
          <data/>
          <data/>
          <data/>
          <data/>
     </field1>
     <field2>
          <data/>
     </field2>
</root>

Comment: forgot comments cant be multiple lines...

Answer (score 1):

you can transform in a object then show in your form. Here how to transform your json in a object

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/9326146#9326146)